# Z-index issues with a fixed element on safari

Tags: html, css, css-position

first of here's the site I'm working with... http://2acr.es I'm having an issue specifically on safari. I want the page to scroll over the "hero" section that's the large image. If you open in chrome you can see what I mean. In safari it's sitting behind the hero even though my main div is set to relative and has a higher z-index. what's even more weird, when you scroll far enough up and shrink the logo it pops on top and works fine. Also if you refresh the page with it half way scrolled up it works fine.

Is this a weird bug with safari? any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the concern but it's not quite a problem that I can post code to as it would be ALOT of code... Also I'm not sure which part of the code is the issue so posting it all here wouldn't help narrow anything down. The best situation is to see the problem in action